# Javascript: How do I create a function that can generate an X amount of objects drawing from fixed amount of classes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For my coding assignment, I'm tasked with creating a function that can generate an X amount of objects drawing from fixed amount of classes. But while the objects are being generated, I would like to store those objects in an array. How would I go about doing this in Javascript?

Comment: Use a loop and `push`

Comment: I know how to generate random objects when only two classes are available: var outputPara =  document.getElementById("output"), 
        someKindOfGradedActivity,
        randNum=Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

Comment: How do create something that randomly selects from more than two classes? With this: randNum=Math.floor(Math.random()*2, I can make select from two possible classes because the answer is either going to be 0 or 1.

Comment: Do you want to avoid duplicate classes in the resulting array ?

Comment: Not at all. I just want to generate then array and then loop through and print out the randomly generated values.

Comment: Ok, does my answer fit your needs?

Comment: I don't have an array to begin with. I want to generate an array full of random object from three classes (Ex. new Horse(), new Pig(), new Rat()). How do generate an X amount of objects given the three classes as examples while storing them in an array?

Comment: @CaZ OK, I changed my answer a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same as you would do for two objects. Just use the length of the array to pick a random element, and use a loop to perform the action X times:

```js
/* Class definitions */
function Animal(){ var a = document.createElement('div'); a.className = 'animal'; return a}
function Horse(){ var a = new Animal(); a.className += ' horse'; return a }
function Pig(){ var a = new Animal(); a.className += ' pig'; return a }
function Rat(){ var a = new Animal(); a.className += ' rat'; return a }

/* Variable definitions */
var animals = ['Horse', 'Pig', 'Rat'],
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    numberOfDraws = 5,
    res = [];

/* Auxiliary functions */
// Returns a random element from a given array
function pickRandom(arr){
    return arr[ Math.floor( Math.random()*arr.length ) ];
}

/* Main script */
// Pick a random object 5 times, store it in 'res' and show it
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfDraws; i++){
  res.push( eval('new ' + pickRandom(animals) + '()') );
  output.appendChild( res[i] );
}
```

```css
.animal{float:left;padding:40px;background-size:100%}.horse{background-image:url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/587037647966613504/Mk5oEKsb.png)}.pig{background-image:url(https://33.media.tumblr.com/avatar_c2b180faa484_128.png)}.rat{background-image:url(http://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_614c66cef635_128.png)}
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

**EDIT:** To get an instance of the class, you can `eval` the class name. See the demo above.